# How to get rid of the scroll bar in tmux

Tags: tmux, scrolling

I'm new to tmux and here is a question about tmux.conf. How can I get rid of the scroll bar at the right of the screen, which is totally unnecessary and just takes up precious screen estate?

I thought it would be pretty easy to do it. But after asking Google and Duckduckgo I still couldn't find any viable solutions.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Doi

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that scrollbar is a tmux feature and not terminal emulator's? Is it still there when you detach from tmux?

Comment: Check in the 'view' setting at the top, just like @atype I think that's a terminal emulator thing, not tmux.

Comment: Sorry bros, you are absolutely right. I had a silly concept mistake here. The scroll bar is indeed related to the terminal emulator, which in my case is the xfce terminal.

Comment: The strange thing is that after a quick search in Google and browsing through the help document of xfce terminal, I still could not figure out how to  get rid of the scroll bar. If anyone happens to know the answer, please let me know. Otherwise, I will keep searching.

Comment: http://ubuntuportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/XFCE-4-12-terminal.jpg